# Using Xcode Storyboards for rich rotating UI's

Tags: ios, xcode4, interface-builder, rotation, segue

I am working on an iPad app that relies on a rather complex layout that seems to be beyond the abilities to the auto-resizing masks to rotate cleanly from portrait to landscape.

I can easily enough hand-tweak a layout in Interface Builder for each orientation, but I am puzzling over the most elegant and maintainable way to handle making the transition between the two different layouts.

Is there any way that this can be done with segues?

Is there a way I can easily snapshot two different layouts and use code to morph between them?

Am I better off trying to use HTML5 to do the page layout and not UILabels?

Are there other better techniques that I haven't even thought of yet?

Help is much appreciated - it seems like this shouldn't be so hard.

Answer (score 0):

All you scenes may or may not need to have their own subclass (depending on inheritance).  Assign the subclass to the respective scene.

You then need to set the supported rotation values in the subclass. eg.:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```

EDIT:

I suggest loading a respective NIB by overriding willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:.

Comment: I don't think that I understand how this answer is related to my question...  How does subclassing help with layout issues and segues?